# Lambda capturing instance variable

Tags: java, lambda

From reading the JLS after a frustrating debugging session I find that lambdas will capture the *value* of effectively-final local variables, but if you refer to an instance variable it captures a reference to the variable, which has serious implications for multi-threaded code.

For example, the following is an MCVE distilled from a much larger program:

```
public class LambdaCapture
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        Launcher i1 = new Launcher();
        i1.launchAsynchTask();
    }

    public static class Launcher
    {
        private int value = 10;

        public void launchAsynchTask() throws Exception
        {
            System.out.printf("In launchAsynchTask value is %s\n",value);
            Thread t = new Thread(()->doSomething(value));
            t.start();
            value = -1;
            t.join();
        }

        public void doSomething(int value)
        {
            System.out.printf("In asynch task, value is %s\n",value);
        }
    }
}
```

I found the output surprising. It is

```
In launchAsynchTask value is 10
In asynch task, value is -1
```

since I initially (prior to JLS research) and intuitively expected the lambda to capture the *value* of the variable `value` instead of a reference to it.

If I have to guarantee that the current *value* is captured instead of a reference the obvious solution is to create a local final temporary:

```
        final int capture = this.value;
        Thread t = new Thread(()->doSomething(capture));
```

My question: Is this the accepted idiomatic way to force value capture, or is there some other more natural way to do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I ... intuitively expected the lambda to capture the value of the variable value instead of a reference to it.

That (capturing the value) is what happens with local variables.

With fields, what is actually happening is that you are capturing a reference to the instance of the object that the field belongs to.  In your case, it is a reference to the `Launcher.this` object.  (The same thing happens when you declare an inner class.)

> My question: Is this the accepted idiomatic way to force value capture, or is there some other more natural way to do it?

I can't think of a better way.

Comment: One *could* argue that the "accepted idiomatic way" to prevent the problem presented here, is to make the class immutable. That way the *field* `value` is also "effectively final". Of course, one would have to be a dedicated functional programmer to make that argument. *(I'm not one of them)*

Comment: And implementing *that* in Java would have such a fundamentally disruptive effect that lambdas would be dead in the water ... in the minds of most Java programmers.

Answer (score 3):

Because you're using shorthand syntax, it's not as obvious what is going on.

When you write `value` to access the *field*, it implicitly means `this.value`.

The lambda expression is capturing the absolutely final "local variable" `this` that is implicit to all non-static methods.

The lambda expression

```
()->doSomething(value)
```

is *logically* equivalent to

```
new Lambda$1(this)
```

where `Lambda$1` is declared like this *(using arbitrary names)*:

```
private static final class Lambda$1 implements Runnable {
    private final Launcher ref;
    Lambda$1(Launcher ref) {
        this.ref = ref;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.ref.doSomething(this.ref.value);
    }
}
```

As you can see, the lambda expression `()->doSomething(value)` is not actually capturing `value`. The unqualified field access is obscuring what is actually happening.

---

*FYI:* Hiding field `value` behind parameter `value` in the `doSomething()` method is a bad idea. The name conflict makes the code very vulnerable to misinterpretation by programmers, and good IDEs will warn you about it *(unless you disabled that warning)*.

Hopefully that just happened by mistake here when creating an MCVE, and you wouldn't do that in real code. :-)

Answer (score 2):

What I normally like to do is to minimize code parts that access fields directly, so you could wrap the part starting the thread in a function like this:

```java
public void launchAsynchTask() throws Exception
{
    System.out.printf("In launchAsynchTask value is %s\n", this.value);
    Thread t = launchAsynchTaskWithValue(this.value);
    this.value = -1;
    t.join();
}

public Thread launchAsynchTaskWithValue(int launchValue) throws Exception
{
    Thread t = new Thread(()->doSomething(launchValue));
    t.start();
    return t;
}
```